# How to filter records from a file using bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I'm supposed to filter records from multiple files. Files are delimited by `|`. On the 24th field, I will filter the records by "9120". How am I supposed to filter the files by using bash script?

```
20|09328833007|0|0|9222193385|0|GS|515051032704315|0|*HOME||20140311|101640|0|0|‌​||12|18|0|0|1||3100|00886FC0||0|0|| |||N|N|||N||||N|||||| 301131301|||||||||||11|0||00|FF|11|FF|140311101640|352912058113130000||CEBS1|MSH‌​15
```

Comment: by writing some code?

Comment: what do you mean by : "Files are delimited by '|'"?

Comment: The records inside a file are delimited by '|'.

Comment: can you show some line of file...

Comment: 20|09328833007|0|0|9222193385|0|GS|515051032704315|0|*HOME||20140311|101640|0|0|||12|18|0|0|1||3100|00886FC0||0|0|| |||N|N|||N||||N|||||| 301131301|||||||||||11|0||00|FF|11|FF|140311101640|352912058113130000||CEBS1|MSH15    --- Im going to filter the 24th field

Answer (score 2):

The more concise way using awk:

```
awk '$24=="9120"'  FS='|' file*
```

Using variable input:

```
 awk -v col=24 -v value="9120" '$col==value'  FS='|' file*
```

Answer (score 1):

awk is useful to processing files like this. You set the `FIELD SEPARATOR` to `|`:

To print the 24th field:

```
$ awk -F '|' '{ print $24 }' sample.txt
3100
```

To print lines where the 24th field is the value you specified:

```
awk -F '|' '$24=="9120" { print; }' sample.txt
```

Comment: +1, but you can drop the `{ print ; }` as it's implicit.

Comment: Hi @MattH , print is useless in the second example, because is the default action when a condition evaluates to true.

Comment: @klashxx, noted. However, sometimes when you're helping people it's better to spell out implicit behaviour rather than just dazzle them with tacit knowledge.

Comment: You're right .. cheers @MattH

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how if I want to filter the 24th column by '9120' , '3100' and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat file* | awk -F"|" '$24=="9120" {print $0}'
```